# Using a variable through a Query located in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a procedure that is supposed to take queries from a table and run them. This works fine except when I try to define a variable in the procedure that is referenced in the query. I simply define the variable using:

```
DECLARE @spcode as varchar(255)
SET @spcode = 'C'
```

And then in the table I reference it here:

```
...
where sp_flag = @spcode
...
```

My procedure then runs through the table and executes all of the queries in the table, this works if I simply set sp_flag = 'C', but if I try to set it to the variable defined in the procedure I get the following error:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@spcode".
```

I have searched around but I have not been able to find a solution to this problem, perhaps someone has an idea of how I would go about fixing this problem?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: sp_executesql: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: You are saying I should use sp_executesql in place of EXECUTE?

Comment: How you execute queries from table?

Comment: Have you tried `SET @sql = replace(@sql, @spcode, '''C''')`?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example.

First snippet execute SQL statement without using variable. Second with.

```
create table tbl1 (id int identity(1,1), value varchar(100));  
insert into tbl1 (value) values ('abc'), ('def'), ('xyz');

-- first snippet (without using variable)
declare
    @sql varchar(max);

set @sql = 'select * from tbl1 where value = ''abc''';

exec(@sql);



-- second snippet (with variable)
declare
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @param nvarchar(100);

set @param = N'@val varchar(100)'
set @sql = N'select * from tbl1 where value = @val';

exec sp_executesql @sql, @param, @val = 'abc';
```